# blkid: blkid_probe_lookup_value() - strange partition types

Tags: linux, mount, system-programming, libblkid

I need to check filesystem type on a thumb drive in my C++ application. It must be done before mounting a new partition. I also prefer not to call `system()` function. I tried to use the following test code:

```
#include <blkid/blkid.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    blkid_probe pr;
    const char *ptname;
    const char* devname = "/dev/sdb1";
    pr = blkid_new_probe_from_filename(devname);
    if (!pr)
        printf("faild to open device\n");
    else
    {
        blkid_probe_enable_partitions(pr, true);
        blkid_do_fullprobe(pr);

        blkid_probe_lookup_value(pr, "PTTYPE", &ptname, NULL);
        printf("%s partition type detected\n", ptname);

        blkid_free_probe(pr);   
    }
}
```

When I plug in thumb drive with `ntfs` this piece of code shows that my partions is dos. When I plug in thumb drive with `fat` or `ext4` the code returns strange string but the same for these two filesystems:
`AWAVI��AUATL�%�` .

What causes these strange outputs? Maybe there is a better way to check a filesystem?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in what filesystem is on `sdb1` you should use `USAGE` to first check whether it is a `filesystem` and then get filesystem type with `TYPE`.

You'll need to set these flags to enable filesystem lookup:

```
blkid_probe_set_superblocks_flags(probe, BLKID_SUBLKS_USAGE | BLKID_SUBLKS_TYPE |
                                         BLKID_SUBLKS_MAGIC | BLKID_SUBLKS_BADCSUM);
```

About your result: you need to check return value of `blkid_probe_lookup_value` (or use `blkid_probe_has_value` first), you are not initializing `ptname` to `NULL` so you'll get garbage if the lookup fails. And the lookup will fail, because partitions don't have `PTTYPE`. (I'm not sure why it worked for you with NTFS, in my case both NTFS and ext4 partition don't have `PTTYPE`.)

Version with usage and type could look like this

```
#include <blkid/blkid.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    blkid_probe pr;
    const char *value = NULL;
    const char* devname = "/dev/sdb1";
    int ret = 0;
    pr = blkid_new_probe_from_filename(devname);
    if (!pr)
        printf("faild to open device\n");
    else
    {
        blkid_probe_enable_partitions(pr, 1);
        blkid_probe_set_superblocks_flags(pr, BLKID_SUBLKS_USAGE | BLKID_SUBLKS_TYPE |
                                              BLKID_SUBLKS_MAGIC | BLKID_SUBLKS_BADCSUM);
        blkid_do_fullprobe(pr);

        ret = blkid_probe_lookup_value(pr, "USAGE", &value, NULL);
        if (ret != 0) {
                printf("lookup failed\n");
                return 1;
        } else
                printf("usage: %s\n", value);

        if (strcmp(value, "filesystem") != 0) {
                printf("not filesystem\n");
                return 1;
        }

        ret = blkid_probe_lookup_value(pr, "TYPE", &value, NULL);
        if (ret != 0) {
                printf("lookup failed\n");
                return 1;
        } else
                printf("type: %s\n", value);

        blkid_free_probe(pr);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much:)